# Hiding a column from the search results

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following javascript function which gets called on selecting an option from a dropdown box on a jsp page :

```
 function getApplication(val)
 {

$("#accVerMessageDiv").html("");

 var accVersion = document.getElementById("account_version").value;
// var optionValue = accVersion.options[accVersion.selectedIndex].value;

if(accVersion == "0"){

    disable();
}
if(accVersion == ""){
    alert("Please select any Application");
    disable();

}
else
{
    enable();
}
document.getElementById("rowDataIdAccountVersion").value=accVersion;
 $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "CalculateFTE",  
        data: {"action":"searchData",
            "account_version":accVersion},  
        success: function(data,jqXHR){
            $("#accVerMessageDiv").html("");
             var col = [];
             for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                 for (var key in data[i]) {
                     if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                         col.push(key);
                     }
                 }
             } 
            /*  for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                 col[i] = col[i].toUpperCase();
             }  */

             //col.push("Actions"); 
             // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
            var table = document.createElement("table");

             // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

             var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

              for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                 var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
                 th.style.backgroundColor = "#c1c1c1";
                 th.innerHTML = col[i].toUpperCase();
                 tr.appendChild(th);
             } 

             // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                 tr = table.insertRow(-1);

                 for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                     var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                     //alert("==data[i]=="+i+"==[col[j]]=="+j+"==="+data[i][col[j]]);
                     var primKey = data[i][col[3]] ;
                    /*  if(data[i][col[j]] == undefined && j==4)
                     {
                        // tabCell.innerHTML = "";
                         //tabCell.innerHTML = '<a href=\"edit.jsp?accId='+primKey+'\">EDIT</a>';
                         tabCell.innerHTML = '<a href=\"javascript:rowEditApplication('+primKey+')\">EDIT</a>';

                     }
                     else */ if(data[i][col[j]] == undefined)
                     {
                         tabCell.innerHTML = "";
                     }
                     else
                         tabCell.innerHTML = data[i][col[j]];
                 }
             } 

             // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
             var divContainer = document.getElementById("searchDataAccountVersion");
             divContainer.innerHTML = "";
             divContainer.appendChild(table); 


        }, 
        error:function(data,jqXHR)
        {

            $("#accVerMessageDiv").html("No Data Found.");
            //$("#accMessageDiv").html(data);
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
                // setting a timeout

        },
        complete: function()
        {

        }
      }); 
 }
```

Following is the HTML code :

```
 <div id="Application">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Application Creation</legend>
                     <div id="appMessageDiv"></div></br>
                <% 
                if((String)session.getAttribute("error") != null){ %>
                <h4><%=session.getAttribute("error")%></h4>
                <%}else if((String)session.getAttribute("message") != null){ %>
                <h4><%=session.getAttribute("message")%></h4>
                <%} %>
                <form method="post" name="applicationForm" id="applicationForm">
                    <label for="appName">Application Name:</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="appName" id="appName" /> <br /> 
                    <label for="appFte">No. of Licenses:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="appFte" id="appFte" /> <br />
                    <label for="contactPerson">Contact Person:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type="text" name="contactPerson" id="contactPerson" /> <br />
                    <label for="account">Account To Be Selected:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select name ="account" id="account" onchange=" getContact(); ">

                    </select> <br />                        
                    <br /> <input type="button" value="Create Application" onclick="createApplication(); ">
                    <input type="button" value="Search Application" onclick="searchApplication();">
                </form>
                </fieldset>
                <div id="searchDataContainer">
                    <fieldset>
                    <legend>Search Result:</legend>
                        </br>

                        </br>
                        <div id="searchDataApplication"></div>
                        <form name="editApplicationForm" id="editApplicationForm">
                            <input type="hidden" id="rowDataIdApplication" name="rowDataIdApplication" value="" />
                        </form>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I want to hide the 3rd column from the results which will be viewed on the jsp page after selecting any option from the dropdown box. There are in total 4 columns which are present in the results. I want to hide the last column. Please help me to achieve this.

Comment: I have added the HTML code now. Please help.

Comment: Do you got CSS as well ? Maybe you could use `:last-child` selector in your table, to get the last column elements.

Comment: Or `:nth-child()`